# C - Should I specify the mount type every time?

Tags: c, kernel, system-calls

I want your opinion about a syscall: mount().

Today, a problem brought back this doubt.
I see a lots of code that calls/uses mount() syscall.
But, recently, running Valgrind, it showed an error saying that you
cannot specify NULL as the 'type' argument of mount function.

An example from kernel code:

```
ret = mount("/dev/pts/ptmx", "/dev/ptmx", NULL, MS_BIND, NULL);
```

Valgrind was complaining about the first NULL parameter which refers
to the mount type:

```
==18012== Syscall param mount(type) points to unaddressable byte(s)
```

After replacing NULL to type "none" the error disappeared.
I read a documentation about it, saying that is better to use "none"
for BIND and MOVE options. But, I'm not right about that.

The x86_64 bits does not use the type for BIND and MOVE. If I read the code of the right arch.

Do you have any documentation or a best practice to use this syscall?

Comment: "After replacing NULL to type "none" the error disappeared." I saw two NULL whitch one did you replace ? "Do you have any documentation or a best practice to use this syscall?" I don't think valgrind tell you that for nothing.

Comment: The manual of mount never specifies that NULL is a valid argument.

Comment: @Stargateur the first NULL argument which refers to mount fs type: int mount(const char *source, const char *target, const char *filesystemtype, unsigned long mountflags, const void *data);

Comment: I do not understand your question; the manpage says: "Specify the mounttype", then you specify the mounttype, which you didn't previously, now it works. Where's the problem?

Comment: Valgrind complains about the first NULL. The question is: I read some suggestions about using "none" to replace the NULL of the fs type. But, I'm not right about it.

Comment: Requests for off-site resources are off-topic, and questions about best practices are often inappropriate as questions about matters of opinion.  I think you have a *bona fide* technical question underneath that; if so, then please edit to reveal it.

Comment: ... but be aware that Linux syscalls (or at least glibc's wrappers for them) have easily locatable manual pages, both online (Google is your friend), and probably also installed on your system.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the main question of this topic is how to avoid this Valgrind issue. I requested a best practice because I saw this kind of call inside the kernel sources too. So, I admit that it works, but not as recommended.

Comment: No, @jcfaracco, you already know how to avoid Valgrind reporting an issue, so that cannot be the main question.

Answer (score 1):

When passing `MS_BIND` to `mount()` among the flags, passing `NULL` as the third argument is not wrong, and passing `"none"` is neither better nor worse.  *Both* rely on the fact that that argument is ignored for bind mounts (and this is documented [in the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html)).

Valgrind is right that `NULL` is a pointer that does not point to data, and that when presented as an argument, `"none"` decays to a pointer that does point to data.  It is not discerning enough to recognize that that does not matter here.  If silencing Valgrind about the issue is your primary concern, then passing `"none"` is a fine way of doing so.

Myself, I'd probably just use `NULL`, as that better conveys to others (including future me) that I'm passing something that I do not expect to be used.  For the same reason, if I were to use a string here to mollify a petulant Valgrind, then I'd probably choose one more like `"not used because MS_BIND"`.

On the other hand, when the mount data are stored in a file (*i.e.* `/etc/fstab`) you have to put something in the field, and *there*, "none"
does a great job of conveying the information that is important at that level, to the human consumers of that data.

Comment: Since it isn't allowed in the manpage, why would you ever use NULL? It might break with the next patchlevel of the libc or in some other environment

Comment: @Ctx, the manapage does not explicitly allow *any* particular value for that argument (it gives only examples of arguments that might be supported) and it does not specifically *dis*allow `NULL`.  It does, on the other hand, explicitly say that the argument in question is ignored in the OP's case.  I have no problem relying on that aspect of the documentation to conclude that the behavior is well defined and consistent no matter what the argument is, so long as it has the correct type.

Comment: Yes, it states the allowed values: "Values for the filesystemtype argument supported by the kernel are listed in /proc/filesystems (e.g., "minix", "ext2", "ext3", "jfs", "xfs", "reiserfs", "msdos", "proc", "nfs", "iso9660").". If there is a list of allowed values, it is concludent to assume, that any other value is disallowed.

Comment: No, @Ctx.  It states *where to find* allowed values (`/proc/filesystems`).  The values presented are examples (that's precisely what "e.g." means).  You will no doubt observe that `NULL` is not listed in `/proc/filesystems`, but neither is `"none"`, at least on my machine.  Using either one relies on "If mountflags includes `MS_BIND` [... t]he `filesystemtype` and `data` arguments are ignored."  Again, I'm just fine with such reliance.

Comment: "It states where to find allowed values" is "stating the allowed values". Yes, from "/proc/filesystems" and yes, the values there are examples. Why do you start hairsplitting here? Do you imply that I cannot read and comprehend such simple sentences? This is quite rude. Yes, if "none" isn't listed either, it shouldn't be used. Easy as that. Do what you want and be fine as you want, but I think you shouldn't recommend such unsafe things to others.

Comment: I am not hairsplitting, @Ctx.  I am pointing out that although there are values that are very likely to be among those supported on a given system(e.g. "ext3") there are none that are *guaranteed* to be supported everywhere.  I guess, then, your solution would be to read `/proc/filesystems` and choose some listed filesystem type to specify to `mount()`, even though that's not actually applicable to the request.  But that's just not the way it is normally done, and it anyway would rely just as much on the specified argument not being used as anything I have suggested does.